# How align 2 buttons in a row using auto layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Basically, I want to align 2 buttons in the same row, with about 1/3 responsive spacing between buttons and edges, like the following picture:

[image: IMG]

However, what's inside the simulator is like this:

[image: img]

Constraints added for each button are:

[image: IMG]

Therefore, is there any way to align these 2 buttons correctly in a row using auto layout?

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive spacing? Do you want to have the 3 horizontal spaces present to be equal, no matter the screen size?

Comment: I mean the spacing in between is about 1/3 depends on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "spacer" view like this:

[image: screenshot]

constraint like
`H:|[spacer1][button1(120)][spacer2(==spacer1)][button2(120)][spacer3(==spacer1)]|`

Answer (score 1):

Control drag from one button to the other button, select horizontal spacing.

Comment: I already tried to set horizontal spacing in between, and the result is exactly the second picture.

Comment: Make sure you set enough constraints in Storyboard, which means there is no red arrow in it.

Comment: The first image shows all constraints added to them and there is no warning with their positions and sizes.

Comment: Can you share your code? I can't reproduce the constraints in the picture. Especially Trailing space to My promotions. Looks to me My promotions is the superview of the All promotions.